# Stop `open` command from opening two apps instead of one?

Tags: terminal, safari, macos

My default browser is DuckDuckGo, but for a particular task it doesn't work.  So in a script (zsh) I invoke Safari in a loop with:

```
  open  -a /Applications/Safari.app               \
           $(grep $DIR $VER | awk '{print $2}')
```

The loop control variable is $VER and $DIR is constant within the script.  There is no other `open` in the script.  There are always seven iterations of $VER.  When I run the script, I get all seven in Safari tabs, but I also get four of them in DuckDuckGo tabs!

Now it's easy enough to kill DuckDuckGo after running the script, but **how do I debug this and/or make it not happen?**

**Clarification**—Actually, open is called twice, but the other one launches TextEdit:

```
for VER in $GRK NTLH HTB ICL NIV NVI NLT; do
  touch $DIR/$(grep $DIR $VER | awk '{print $3}')   # make sure the text file exists
  open  $DIR/$(grep $DIR $VER | awk '{print $3}')   # open the text file
  open  -a /Applications/Safari.app               \
           $(grep $DIR $VER | awk '{print $2}')     # open the web page for the audio
  echo "$DIR/$(grep $DIR $VER | awk '{print $3}')"  # echo the paths to Terminal
  echo      "$(grep $DIR $VER | awk '{print $2}')"
done
```

**Update:** I tried to edit the script, but I said `open` instead of `open -e` by mistake.  So of course, it created a new Terminal window, and ran in that window—without launching DuckDuckGo!  The quote marks someone suggested didn’t help.

Comment: Are you saying you get seven instances of Safari?

Comment: There seems to be some missing context here, but to address the prima fasciae issue, the `open` command will open a new instance of an app.  However, if you want to open an existing instance and create a new tab, for example, use `osascript`.  Example:  `osascript -e "tell Safari activate blah blah blah"`

Comment: Actually, I don't think it opened multiple instances of either app.  Each had one window with multiple tabs.  But four of those URIs were in both apps.

Comment: First, you can check that a file exists with the `-e` conditional. Example:  `[[ -e $DIR/the_result_of_the_grep_and_awk ]]`; this will return a true/false value.  When you `touch` it will create the file if it doesn't exist meaning it will never fail.  Second, you're `grep`-ping and `awk`-ing when all of this can be done in `awk` with pattern matching:  `awk '/pattern1/ {print $3}`.   Finally, I think all of this can be done with an associative array, streamlining this substantially.  However, we'd need to know what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @Allan I though `open` only generated new instances with the `-n` flag. I've just run `open -a TextEdit` six times (with TextEdit already running), and I get no new instances.

Comment: You are correct @benwiggy; I could have worded it better but it's now moot as the OPs latest edit, shows two separate `open` commands opening two distinct applications - Safari and the default browser (DDG)

Comment: Two open commands showing _three_ applications.  The first opens a text file with TextEdit (each iteration).  The second launches both Safari and DuckDuckGo but in DuckDuckGo, three of the seven web pages weren't there.

Comment: I know I can check whether it exists, but in this case I _always_ want to create it if needed before editing.  Since TextEdit (unlike `vi`) won't create automatically, `touch` ensures that `open` won't fail.  The files named by the variable VER are three already created files with over a thousand lines each.  I could read each file into an associative array, but reading the values from the file is easier.  $DIR would be the index into the array but this way it is the first item on the selected line and the other two items are the files to edit/create and the URI to download from.

Comment: I'm also encountering the same problem as OP upon trying to solve OP's problem. When I run `open -a /Applications/Safari.app 'https://www.google.com'`, two browsers open to the webpage, my default browser Google Chrome and the target browser Safari. When I run `open -a /Applications/DuckDuckGo.app 'https://www.google.com'`, only the DuckDuckGo.app opens to the webpage, which is I think what the OP wants. When I run `open -a '/Applications/Google Chrome.app' 'https://www.google.com'`, it opens in my default browser Google Chrome. Something is going on with default browser/`Safari.app`/`open`.